# Notepad++ save failed

Tags: html, notepad++

I'm actually working under `notepad++` for my internship. I work on a website, and I have to deal with HTML, css, django etc. When I make modifications on the python part, I can upload the change without problems, same for the HTML, but since yesterday, when I change something in a html file or even if I open a random HTML file without changing anything in it, when I save the file I got an *Upload of root_of_file failed* but I don't have this message on over type of languages.
Can you help me pls

Thank you

Comment: Check permissions. Also re-install NPP. Create issue in https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/

Comment: Please check the file permissions and the flags (like read only) when you right click the file in the explorer and click on properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be caused by the path you're trying to save the file into. It usually happens when saving files into a root directory (secure location) or shared drives. Try to contact your system administrator, running Notepad++ as admin or changing the path where you're trying to save the file into. Hope this helps!

Try using Visual Studio Code as your IDE.

Comment: Advertising for an IDE? You might say that you prefer that in that case you could explain why that one is better out of your view

Comment: It's based on personal preference, not suggesting one is better over the other. Really depends on what rocks your boat, but I'm just gonna throw the words cross platform and source control integration out there.